# Images don't display when embedded, but do when directly visited

Tags: php, image, apache, apache2

For some reason, on my server, images do not display if they're remotely (or locally) embedded in an HTML page, but they do work when visited directly.

Embed code:

```
<img src="http://c.beastsmc.com/banners/creative.png"/>
```

Here's a fiddle showing the image not displaying: http://jsfiddle.net/gKHM7/

Here's the direct image, which works: http://c.beastsmc.com/banners/creative.png

The .htaccess file is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: They are probably detecting and blocking hotlinking

Comment: The fiddle correctly displays the image for me.

Comment: Possibly an adblocker running in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jcansyi mentioned above (upvote him!), the problem was that AdBlocker blocked the image. The reason it was blocking it was the name of the folder (banners). AdBlockPlus blocks any URL with /banners/ in it.